# Calling Javascript from C# Windows Phone App - Is it a good method?

Tags: javascript, c#, android, windows-phone-8.1, sinch

I'm looking into backend services for developing a cross-platform communication app (target devices are iOS, Android, and Windows Phone). Currently, I'm looking at [Sinch](https://www.sinch.com/).

I'm starting prototype dev on Android for now, and Sinch has an Android-native SDK. However, it does not have a WP-native SDK.

Sinch *does* have a Javascript SDK.

I know that you can write Javascript + HTML apps for Windows Phone right out of the box. I have developed for WP before but only in C#, and I like the features available and I believe (correct me if I'm wrong) that Javascript + HTML runs as a web-browser-based app rather than natively like C#.

So, looking into the future, it seems that I may have trouble porting my app to Windows Phone (which is my favorite platform).

I have looked into calling Javascript code from C#. From what I have read, it seems that you can use a Browser object to evaluate Javascript code from a C# app.

My question is this: would it be feasible to write the majority of my Windows Phone app in C# and then use the Sinch Javascript library when the time comes to send messages? Would this cause major stability problems?

I'd rather not have a full-screen web browser app.

Is it possible to hide the web browser object and simply use it to evaluate Javascript code? Or is there any easier way to obtain this interop?

Thanks for any responses!

EDIT: Let me know if you think it may be worth just going with a full out Javascript+HTML implementation of my app and forget about the C#.

Comment: I work at sinch, the Javascript SDK will not work on non webrtc browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using messaging YES
If you are trying to do calling NO